# Print selected array element having matched key with given string

Tags: php, arrays

I have a first array with:

```
$first_array = Array
(
    "1" => "Loading dock",
    "2" => "Forklift"
);
```

and, a second string with:

either case 1:

`$second_string = 1;`

or case 2:

`$second_string = 2;`

or case 3:

`$second_string = 1,2;`

I want to print value of

- first array

in which matched with the keys of **first array** with value of **second string**.

I have tried this:

```
$first_array [$second_string];
```

It works fine with case 1 & 2 for case 3 I need help....!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need such situation why not to try something like this:

```
$first_array = Array
(
"1" => "Loading dock",
"2" => "Forklift"
);

// $new_array = []; // use this if you want to make new array
$second_string = [1];
// $second_string = [1,2];

if(is_array($second_string)) {
  foreach($second_string as $k=>$s) {
     // $new_array[$s] = $first_array[$s];
     echo $first_array[$s]; // if you only want to print value
  }
}
```

Send your second_string in terms of array which will be best at this situation.